# Android Studio gradle error during generateDebugSource step

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm having some trouble with Android Studio. During the gradle build I get an error such as:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Artifact 'support-annotations.jar (com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.0)' not found.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/C:/Users/MyPc/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/23.0.0/support-annotations-23.0.0.jar
```

I developed my project in compliance with API 22. I have installed API 23 and my project gave some errors. Thus to solve this issue I deleted all things related to API 23. During deletion this file must have deleted. How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Please show your `build.gradle` files.

Comment: Or follow this to set it up. https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/support-annotations

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I removed studio and reinstalled. but now it gives an error " Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
> Unable to delete directory: .." . this compiler will make me leave my profession

Comment: That means some other process is "holding on" to that directory. Close all your file explorers and command lines

Comment: Actually this happened changing package name and folders. at first , package name was **com.myapp.x.y** . then I changed it to **com.myapp.y** by moving y folder to myapp folder. then I deleted x folder. and finally I tried to clean project and got this error

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd get an error about a dependency when you do that. And there is am option in Android Studio to rename / refactor the package, so you probably shouldn't have manually moved anything

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you. Yes.moving files manually is my fault. problem was solved. for those who encounter this problem 1- Quit Android Studio 2- Kill all processes related to Java and adt 3- Go to that directory and delete it 4- Reopen studio and click _Sync Project with Gradle Files_

Comment: You're welcome to provide that as an answer below.